# CakePHP 3.2: DebugKit error when opening panel

Tags: debugging, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I try to open any panel in DebugKit, CakePHP logo just keeps spinning and I can see there is an error in console. This is the error that I get :

> Call to undefined method App\Controller\Component\MyComponent::configKey()

Which is strange because this component works totally fine and it doesn't show any errors when I use it in the application.

Comment: For future questions, please don't make up names like `MyComponent`, always use the real ones, as you figured the name was the problem here - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the error. My components name was *Cookie* and DebugKit plugin uses component with this name as well, so plugin was trying to call function *configKey*, which of course could not be found in my component.